# Eclipse Egit and Remote Repo Sync

Tags: github

Currently am working with Git Repo and i have  a fellow team mate also ,after he commit to the remote repo and i get all the changes . I have couple of questions

1. When i merge the code with Changes then the changed file in my work space is marked as staged, do i need to commit to local repo?
2. I have a read lot of documentation and still am confused with the best way of sync,

   Currently i do following steps:

   Go to Team->Sync Workspace-> Fetch From Upstream->Mege . Please correct if am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, the [Egit manual](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pulling_New_Changes_from_Upstream_Branch) includes a "pull" operation which would do the fetch+merge in one operation.

> Right-click on a project in the Package Explorer and select **`Team > Pull`** or right-click on a repository in the Git Repositories view and select `Pull` to pull new changes from the upstream branch your local branch is tracking.

Doing a fetch + merge (as in [Egit Merging](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Merging)) will result in a merge commit unless there is a conflict.

- **Real merge**: When neither of the conditions above apply egit triggers a merge of the commits. There are two possible outcomes:

  - If no conflicts occur the current branch will point to a newly created merge commit;
  - if conflicts occur the conflicting files will be marked with label decorators (see [Resolving a merge conflict](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Resolving_a_merge_conflict) for further actions in case of merge conflicts).

You should see staged changes only in the second case (merge conflict to resolve), or you would see stage changes because you previously added to the index files which are not part of the merge (they remain staged until you commit them)